# TOP 1 record from 2 different tables using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, let's call them `[Table1]` and `[Table2]`.

I need to get the TOP 1 record from both tables

```
where [ChargeDate] > dateadd(hh, -1, getdate())
```

The problem is that I am using a CROSS JOIN when there is no record in `[Table1]`.

The result being that no records were returned by the query. Any suggestions on what query I can write which will return records even if there is no data in one of the two tables?

Comment: Please share some sample data and your desired results. I feel like a UNION would be more appropriate here, but without seeing what you are after, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and follow the instructions. (Make it easy yo help you!)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem, I believe you are looking for a [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx):

> All rows in all joined tables are included, whether they are matched
>   or not. For example, a full outer join between titles and publishers
>   shows all titles and all publishers, even those that have no match in
>   the other table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your description sounds like `union all`.  Your description is quite vague, but something like this:

```
select top (1) t.*
from ((select . . .
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select . ..
       from t2
      )
     ) t
order by chargedate desc
```

Comment: If I understand the question the result should show 2 records, TOP 1 of each. Thus the TOP 1 should go into the inner SELECts.